# Show ToolTip of a truncated WPF ListBox Item

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Been searching all over but could not find the answer I am looking for; perhaps I'm not using the correct search term.

Anyways, my question is whether there is a **property** on the WPF ListBox control which I can ***set*** that will automatically display the full text of a **truncated** list item into a ToolTip?

For example, with some WinForm list-container controls, the ToolTip only appears when the mouse is hovered over a list item that is truncated.

Comment: Here are two methods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115924/show-wpf-tooltip-if-needed

Comment: Was hoping for a quick property setting to make it work; will make do with the suggestion, thanks.

Comment: I believe the search term you want is "Tooltip", not "Hint Tip".

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill but here is an article which shows how to determine if text in your control is actually trimmed so that you can show a ToolTip:

http://tranxcoder.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/customizing-lookful-wpf-controls-take-2/

Referenced from this question:

[How can I determine if my TextBlock text is being trimmed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041820/how-can-i-determine-if-my-textblock-text-is-being-trimmed)